# Adding a check for validator if field is not empty

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-4

I have a validator for users to update their profile, and on the same page the user can change their password. Although, I do not want to run a check if all the 3 fields (current password, new / confirmed) is empty.

Is there a way I can add in a custom check in the `Validator::make`and check, or add to the validator and add the return with errors page?

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'first_name' => 'required|max:191',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:191',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:191'
      ]);
```

example 3 field are empty and wouldnt be a problem, although what if they're filled out... can I append to this for check

example

```
if ($request->new_password) {
$validator .= array('new_password' => 'required');
}
```

my last solution would be to have two validators... would that work?

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by adding `sometimes` to your rule list. `sometimes` runs validation checks against a field only if that field is present in the input array. As an exmaple,

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
'email' => 'sometimes|required|email',
]);
```

For more rules options you can refer to [Laravel Validator Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation).